# Print how many substitutions took place in a Perl s///g?

Tags: regex, perl

I've used web search, found similarly titled question [How many substitutions took place in a Perl s///g?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103319/how-many-substitutions-took-place-in-a-perl-s-g) and tried to use it to print the number but have not been able to succeed.

My initial code was

```
perl -0777 -i.original -pe 's-\r\n-\n-igs' test.txt
```

When I tried

```
perl -0777 -i.original -pe "$c=s-\r\n-\n-igs;say qq'$c'" test.txt
```

I got nothing - no output and no replacements, when I tried

```
perl -0777 -i.original -pe '$c=s-\r\n-\n-igs;print qq($c\n)' test.txt
```

(`print` similar to other one-liners I used before) I got empty string in standard output but `454847` added as the beginning of file (and proper replacements).

I understand `=~` is not needed in my case ([What does =~ do in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019049/what-does-do-in-perl)), so what is wrong with my code? How to print number of replacements made?

Comment: @ikegami, archname='x86_64-msys-thread-multi'. It's Git bash on Win7. I do some replacements and now want to see what many were made same as text editor informs after replace command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of `-i`, the default output handle isn't STDOUT but the output file. To print to STDOUT, you'll need to do so explicitly.

If using the `cmd` shell,

```
perl -0777pe"CORE::say STDOUT s/\r//g" -i.original test.txt
```

If using `sh` or similar,

```
perl -0777pe'CORE::say STDOUT s/\r//g' -i.original test.txt
```

Notes:

- `s///` is more idiomatic than `s---`
- `/i` is useless here.
- `/s` is useless here.
- There no point in checking for Line Feeds. `s/\r//g` will work just as fine as `s/\r\n/\n/g`.
- There's point in using a variable for the count, especially if using `say` instead of `print`.
- One must use `CORE::say` instead of `say` for backwards compatibility reasons unless `use feature qw( say );` or equivalent is used.
- Neither `s/\r\n/\n/g` nor `s/\r//g` will work with a Windows build of Perl, and there's no way to do what you want when using `-i` on a Windows build of Perl. However, you are using a unix build of Perl (since MSYS is a unix emulation environment), so it's not an issue.

Comment: I would add to my knowledge here found on the web: `The say function behaves just like the print function, except that it appends a newline at the end of its arguments.` and just fixed code is `perl -0777 -i.original -pe '$c=s-\r\n-\n-igs;CORE::print STDOUT qq($c\n)' test.txt
`. p.s. I originally used ` as separator but stackoverflow use it to denote code. O my I did not guess that number added to the file was my output!

Comment: No need to use `CORE::print` instead of `print`. `say` was added to Perl later, so one must use `CORE::say` for backwards compatibility, unless one uses `use feature qw( say );` or similar. Added this to my answer.

Comment: I'm confused here. Why you wrote `CORE` in your answer?

Comment: That was explained in the previous comment and in my answer.